# How to convert exists condition inside where clause in Linq

Tags: linq

I want to add following where clause to Linq query. How subquery like below using linq

```
WHERE (Restaurants.[IsActive] = 1) 
AND exists 
(
   select 1 from APIKeys 
   where ApiKey = 'on35e5xbt3m4cbcef4e4448t6wssg11o'
       and (KeyType = 1
       and  fk_RestaurantsID = [t2].[RestaurantsID]
       or KeyType = 2 
       and fk_RestaurantGroupID = RG.RestaurantGroupsID 
       and [t1].[fk_RestaurantsID] in 
           (SELECT RestaurantsID 
            FROM Restaurants 
            WHERE RestaurantGroupsID = RG.RestaurantGroupsID))
)
AND (0 = (COALESCE([t0].[fk_MembersID],0))) 
AND (1 = [t0].[fk_BookingStatusID]) 
AND ([t0].[Email] = 'nike.s@gmail.com') 
AND (([t0].[Phone] = '9999999990') OR ([t0].[MobilePhone] = '9999999990'))
```

Comment: Can you simplify your question and provide simple sql query which reproduces problem you faced with?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Any()` to produce subquery which translated to EXISTS. E.g. with AdventureWorks database sample:

```
from p in Products
where p.FinishedGoodsFlag &&
      SalesOrderDetails.Any(od => od.ProductID == p.ProductID)
select new { p.ProductID, p.Name }
```

Will produce following query to database:

```
SELECT [t0].[ProductID], [t0].[Name]
FROM [Production].[Product] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[FinishedGoodsFlag] = 1) AND (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[ProductID] = [t0].[ProductID]
    ))
```

Comment: thanks, i got this, but  not sure about 
and 
(
KeyType = 1 and fk_RestaurantsID = [t2].[RestaurantsID]
or KeyType = 2 and fk_RestaurantGroupID = RG.RestaurantGroupsID and [t1].[fk_RestaurantsID] in (SELECT RestaurantsID FROM Restaurants WHERE RestaurantGroupsID = RG.RestaurantGroupsID)
)

Comment: That's a simple where condition. You can write all this stuff in Any predicate `SalesOrderDetails.Any(...)`, or you can write this way `SalesOrderDetails.Where(...).Any()`. Both will generate EXISTS as you want

Comment: how about adding this last and clause? 
and [t1].[fk_RestaurantsID] in (SELECT RestaurantsID FROM Restaurants WHERE RestaurantGroupsID = RG.RestaurantGroupsID

Comment: @kaustubhshukla try to use another subquery